# Get mappings from feature to one hot encoding dimension

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

So, currently I have bunch of string categorical features which I am transforming to one hot encoding as follows

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

X_str = np.array([['a', 'dog', 'red'], ['b', 'cat', 'green']])
# transform to integer
X_int = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(X_str.ravel()).reshape(*X_str.shape)
# transform to binary
X_bin = OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(X_int).toarray()

print(X_bin)
# [[ 1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
#  [ 0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.]]
```

This works.

But, I am trying to find out the mappings from feature to which dimension is activated

So, for example, 'a' is mapped to 0 (As the 0th index in the feature vector is set to 1)

'b' is mapped to 1 (as the 1st index of feature vector is set to 1)

'cat' is mapped to 2 (as the 2nd index of feature vector is set to 1)

So, I want to get all these mappings in a dictionary .
What's a good way to achieve these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LabelEncoder().classes_`. That will be the order it will be arranged. And most probably that is alphabetic.

That means you will need to save the `LabelEncoder()` object. Use it like this:

```
le = LabelEncoder()
X_int = le.fit_transform(X_str.ravel()).reshape(*X_str.shape)

print(le.classes_)
#Out:- ['a' 'b' 'cat' 'dog' 'green' 'red']
```

You can then use:

```
labels = le.classes_

mappings = {}
for index, label in zip(range(len(labels)), labels):
    mappings[label]=index

print(mappings)
#Out: {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'dog': 3, 'cat': 2, 'green': 4, 'red': 5}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I have a follow up.. What if my feature is something like
`X_str = np.array([[1, 'a', 'dog', 'red'], [2, 'b', 'dog', 'green']])`

now le will only transform the string vars but then `onehotencodenc` will map the first column as well..how do i get their mappings?

Comment: @Fraz I am not understanding. If you replace X_str with your given data then also the labelEncoder will encode them. Check the output :- `{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'dog': 4, '1': 0, '2': 1, 'green': 5, 'red': 6}`

Comment: @Fraz See that the 1 and 2 present in your data are encoded as '1' and '2' . Is this what you want ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LabelEncoder method 'classes_' to get this done. Something like this:

```
#fit, instead of transform and store this
X_enc = LabelEncoder().fit(X_str.ravel())
enc_dct = {}
for idx,items in enumerate(list(X_enc.classes_)):
  enc_dct[idx] = items
print (enc_dct)
#{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'cat', 3: 'dog', 4: 'green', 5: 'red'}
```